# Simpler way to populate a list of 5 random ints

Tags: java

I want to populate an array list with 5 elements randomly from 0 to 4.

Lets say my ArrayList randomizer = new ArrayList();

What I have is the following...

```
 for (int itter = 0; itter < 5; itter++) {
                        do {
                                random = randInt(0, 4);
                        } while (randomizer.contains(random));
                        if (randomizer.contains(random)) {
                        } else {
                                randomizer.add(random);
                        }
```

Is there a faster way to randomly add 5 integers to an arraylist? Thanks!

Comment: Try [Collections.shuffle](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

Comment: Is `Collections.shuffle` not fast enough?  I can think of at least one way that would be quicker - but I can't imagine that the optimisation would be worth the complexity.

Comment: @tobias_K thanks for the doc. David Wallace, I guess I should've rephrased my title to a simpler way/less lengthy. Thanks guys.

Comment: something like that =) http://www.explainxkcd.com/wiki/index.php/221:_Random_Number

Comment: Well, you can edit your question now; and that would make all of the answers that say `Collections.shuffle` correct.  And I won't bother telling you what the faster way is.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try [`Collections.shuffle`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#shuffle%28java.util.List%29)

```
List<Integer> randomizer = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
Collections.shuffle(randomizer);
System.out.println(randomizer);
```

Example output:

```
[3, 4, 2, 0, 1]
```

*Addendum:* Just for completeness, for the question at hand, using `Arrays.asList` is nice and concise, but in the general case, using a `for` loop to populate the initial list is better and much more flexible.

Comment: Thank you tobias_k. I'm waiting to accept the answer.

Comment: +1 you can make this slightly faster by providing a reused `Random`

Comment: Dear anonymous downvoter, please help me to improve my answer by telling my why you downvoted.

Answer (score 3):

```
        LinkedList<Integer> list = new LinkedList<Integer>();
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++) {
            list.add(i);
        }
        Collections.shuffle(list);
```

Comment: This one is my favorite because it is extendable to a list of thousands of integers, where you can't simply type out `1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ... 1232`.

Answer (score 1):

To get this sort of randomized collection then the best way to do it is to use `Collections.shuffle`. Fill your array with the possible values and then do shuffle and you are finished.

(You can also do the same thing to for example pick 10 numbers from 0,100. Fill an array with 100 numbers then shuffle it, then use the first 10).

Answer (score 0):

You can simply shuffle the array

```
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List

public class Test {

   public static void main( String args[] ){
      List X = Arrays.asList(0, 1, 2, 3, 4);
      Collections.shuffle( X );
   }

}
```

Comment: Question is tagged Java.

Answer (score 0):

You would make things quicker by creating a "selection" list first (0, 1, 2, 3, 4). Then go through a loop 4 times (for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) { with int choice = randInt(0,4-i);  add the the selection in that position, remove that position from the selection list and proceed).
After completing the loop put the last remaining selection into your result.

Don't directly try to generate an integer and retry if that integer has already been chosen,